# HermesJMS not getting launched from Soap UI 5.3.0 in mac Sierra

Tags: java, macos, macos-sierra, hermes-jms

HermesJMS not getting launched from Soap UI in mac Sierra after configuring the HermesJMS path in Preferences -> Tools -> Hermes JMS.
On click of Hermes JMS under Tools menu in SOAP UI 5.3.0 in mac java icon/symbol is displaying at the bottom dock but Hermes JMS not getting launched.

Installed Java versions: Java 1.6 and 1.8